# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'Bool' in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string

```
var is_searching: String? = nil

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell        
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ProductCell

    if  is_searching == true
    {
        cell.lblBrndname?.text=(searched_array[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "brand_name") as? String
        cell.Pdtimg?.image  = UIImage(named: icon_Array[indexPath.row])

    }
    else
    {
        cell.lblBrndname?.text=(Specarray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "brand_name") as? String
        cell.Pdtimg?.image = UIImage(named: self.icon_Array[indexPath.row])

    }
    return cell

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How are you supposed to compare whether a `String` is `true` or not? You can compare a `String` with another `String` only.

Comment: how can you compare a string to a bool?

Answer (score 1):

change type of isSearching

```
var is_searching: Bool = false
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString has a boolValue property that you can use:

```
if let is_searching = is_searching as? NSString,
    is_searching.boolValue == true {
  print("String is true")
} else {
  print("String is not true")
```

But the other poster's idea is better. If you can rewrite your code so is_searching is a bool in the first place that would be the better approach.